# Using one or multiple ArrayAdapters and where to place them?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I'm not sure how to correctly build my application. I have an activity that has an array of items. The activity has no GUI. Further on, I have multiple fragments. Each fragment should read (filter) items from my Activity and display the items using the same views. So each item is displayed using the same view. Should I now implement an ArrayAdapter in my activity or should I create multiple ArrayAdapters in my fragments? Unfortunately I'm not used to work with adapters.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share Adapters between AdapterViews if they have the same backing data. But *as a general rule* that's not the case.

In short, unless all AdapterViews (e.g. ListView, Spinner) show the same items, you should use separate Adapters.